# how to print unicode string of chinese characters in python 2.6?

Tags: python, unicode

Here is the chinese string I am trying to print out `統計情報`. I want to see unicode representation python console. This string is in file.
so this is what I tried.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("testutf8.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
     fa=f.read()
     print fa.encode('utf-8')
```

This still prints chinese characters in console.
I want to see unicode string on console

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get Unicode code points instead, like this: `'\xe7\xb5\xb1\xe8\xa8\x88\xe6\x83\x85\xe5\xa0\xb1'`?

Comment: Perhaps `print repr(fa)`, or `print fa.encode("unicode-escape")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'unicode-escape' encoding can show you the codepoints:

```
>>> s = u'統計情報'
>>> print(s.encode('unicode-escape'))
\u7d71\u8a08\u60c5\u5831
```

But if you want to use those integers directly, it's better to apply `ord`:

```
>>> ord(s[0])
32113
>>> 0x7d71
32113
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in s]
['0x7d71', '0x8a08', '0x60c5', '0x5831']
```

What I've described here works on both Python 2 and Python 3.